# PHP documentation plugin for Xcode

Tags: php, xcode

Does anyone know if there are any plugins that allow Xcode to use code completion and documentation for PHP?

I realise [there’s a similar Xcode/PHP question on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/121747/is-there-a-way-to-use-xcode-for-php-web-development?rq=1) but that was from five years ago, I’m hoping things have changed since then!

If not a plugin, maybe some kind of workaround? I realise Coda is supposed to be a great alternative, in terms of Mac IDEs, but it’s pretty expensive and I’m an indie developer!

Also, I know of other apps like NetBeans etc… but I’m looking to see if Xcode is really a no-go before I go and use those clunky IDEs.

Comment: Yeah, I was just hoping for a little more support than basic colouring. Thanks though  Coda it is...